# Add array to object with help of OR operator (||)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, operators

I would like to add some value to an array, which is part of an object.

- If the key value is already in the object: Push to the end of the array
- Else: Create the array

This one works:

```js
let objectWithArr = {};
const key = "Words";

function increaseCount(key, value) {
  if (typeof (objectWithArr[key]) === "undefined") objectWithArr[key] = [value];
  else objectWithArr[key].push(value);
}

increaseCount(key, "Entry 1");
console.log(objectWithArr);
increaseCount(key, "Entry 2");
console.log(objectWithArr);
```

But this one doesn't work:

```js
let objectWithArr = {};
const key = "Words";

function increaseCount(key, value) {
  objectWithArr[key] = objectWithArr[key].push(value) || [value];
}

increaseCount(key, "Entry 1");
console.log(objectWithArr);
increaseCount(key, "Entry 2");
console.log(objectWithArr);
```

Wonder why the second version fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially `objectWithArr['Words']` is undefined. So `undefined.push(value)` is going to elicit `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"`.

Also, [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array, not the array itself.  So your expression `objectWithArr[key].push(value) || [value]` does not do what you intended.

Even if the array initially existed with one item in it, this would return `2` (as we push the second item into the array). e.g. initially:  `objectWithArr = {Words: ['Entry 1']}`.  The expression `objectWithArr['Words'].push('Entry 2')` would return `2` (because the array now contains `2` items, and `push` returns the length after the push).  This means you effectively have `2 || [value]` which is just `2`.  And you now assign `objectWithArr[key] = 2`.  And that ruins the array for any subsequent attempt.

---

All the answers here so far actually create a **new** array.  I believe the intent of the original question was to keep the original array if it exists.  Therefore something like would seem to be necessary, if you do indeed want to keep the original array if it already exists:

```js
let objectWithArr = {};
const key = "Words";

function increaseCount(key, value) {
  (objectWithArr[key] = objectWithArr[key] || []).push(value);
}

increaseCount(key, "Entry 1");
console.log(objectWithArr);
increaseCount(key, "Entry 2");
console.log(objectWithArr);
```

Comment: From a Time-Space-Analysis perspective the most elegant solution, I suppose. Thanks!

Comment: But still struggling a bit with the explanation ("returns the new length"). How to push something to "undefined"? Cause at the very first function call there is no array for "Words", thus I expected the right part of || to be executed.

Comment: @RenéK, I have provided more clarification.

Comment: Finally understood. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd snippet doesn't work, because `Array.push()` returns the length of the array, after the push operation. You can achieve this by using `Array.concat()` or array spread, which will return a new array with the added item:

```js
const objectWithArr = {};
const key = "Words";

function increaseCount(key, value) {
  // spread objectWithArr[key] or an empty array if it doesn't exist, and add the value 
  objectWithArr[key] = [...objectWithArr[key] || [], value];
}

increaseCount(key, "Entry 1");
console.log(objectWithArr);
increaseCount(key, "Entry 2");
console.log(objectWithArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this piece of code: objectWithArr[key].push(value) returns the new length of the array, not the array itself, so you just push the new element into the current array and then objectWithArr[key] is equal to the new length of the array. So the next time you call objectWithArr[key].push you actually doing: 2.push(value) which makes no sense and your array reference is long gone.
Try using:

```
function increaseCount(key, value) {
  objectWithArr[key] = (objectWithArr[key] || []).concat(value);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to `concat` this creates a new array even if the array already exists.  Should be `(objectWithArr[key] = objectWithArr[key] || []).push(value)` to keep the original array if it exists.

Comment: @Wyck Most likely your way is better in terms of performance, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The second one fails as `Array.prototype.push` returns the new length of the Array after inserting the new element.

To make it shorter use `...` spread operator:

```js
let objectWithArr = {};
const key = "Words";

function increaseCount(key, value) {
  objectWithArr[key] = [...(objectWithArr[key] || []), value] 
}

increaseCount(key, "Entry 1");
console.log(objectWithArr);
increaseCount(key, "Entry 2");
console.log(objectWithArr);
```

You can also use the null coalescing operator `??` (to check if array exists or not) with the `Array.prototype.concat` method. The `concat` will return a new instance of the array after the object is inserted:

```js
let objectWithArr = {};
const key = "Words";

function increaseCount(key, value) {
 objectWithArr[key] = (objectWithArr[key] ?? []).concat(value)
}

increaseCount(key, "Entry 1");
console.log(objectWithArr);
increaseCount(key, "Entry 2");
console.log(objectWithArr);
```

You can also use `push` by first initializing the `objectWithArr[key]` with an empty array first then calling `push(value)`, so that no new array instance would be created:

```js
let objectWithArr = {};
const key = "Words";

function increaseCount(key, value) {
  objectWithArr[key] = (objectWithArr[key] || []);
  objectWithArr[key].push(value);
}

increaseCount(key, "Entry 1");
console.log(objectWithArr);
increaseCount(key, "Entry 2");
console.log(objectWithArr);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the spread operator, this creates a new array even if the array already exists.  Same happens in the second example due to `concat`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
Can use ternary operator.

```js
let objectWithArr = {};
const key = "Words";

function increaseCount(key, value) {
  return typeof (objectWithArr[key]) === "undefined" ? objectWithArr[key] = [value] : objectWithArr;
}

increaseCount(key, "Entry 1");
console.log(objectWithArr);
increaseCount(key, "Entry 2");
console.log(objectWithArr);
```